# How to send "google analytics" and "hotjar" tracking client events using server ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics, analytics

I have a situation where there are people browsing our site, I'm using javascript google analytics, and hotjar to track my users.

1. Im tracking users like this :

   ga('send', 'event', '/RegisterButton', '', '');
      hotjar('send', 'event');...

However, there are now events and data that is happening on the server side for those people, that I'd like to track as well (in analytics).

For an example, I would like to know if a person uploaded a file more than once.

How do I do it?

One way, is to do this (this is a psuedo code) :

```
         function clickOnUploadButton()
         {
     var userDetails = ajax_get_user_details(function(data) {
              if (data.numOfClicksOnUploadButton > 1)
                  {
                ga('send', 'event', '/UploadButtonMoreThanOnce', '', '');
                   hotjar('send', '/UploadButtonMoreThanOnce');
                   }
              else
                {
                ga('send', 'event', '/UploadButtonFirstTime', '', '');
                   hotjar('send', '/UploadButtonFirstTime');
                 }

           ajax_activate_my_asp_controller();
          });
    }
```

I don't really want this solution. 
Because then, I send the data to the client side. I normally don't need this data in my web page. And this just complicates the javascript code.

I want a solution so that I can send this data directly to google analytics from the server side.
like this :

in javascript (psuedo code):

```
function clickOnUploadButton() {
   ... do stuff ...
   ajax_activate_my_ASP_controller();
}
```

and in my Server side controller (this is a psuedo code) :

```
void MyController()
{
      string googleAnalyticsSessionID = Request["GoogleAnalyticsSessionID"];
      string hotjarSessionID = Request["HotJarID"];
      var user = GetMyUser();
       if (user.numOfClicksOnUploadButton > 1)
           {
            new GoogleAnalyticsClass().SendEvent(googleAnalyticsSessionID , "button", "UploadButtonMoreThanOnce");
            new HotJar().SendEvent(hotjarSessionID, "button" "UploadButtonMoreThanOnce");
          }
      else
             {
           new GoogleAnalyticsClass().SendEvent(googleAnalyticsSessionID , "button", "UploadButtonFirstTime");
          new HotJar().SendEvent(hotjarSessionID, "button" "UploadButtonFirstTime");
          }
}
```

Thanks.

**Edit : I also need this for hotjar (a service similar to google analytics) as well...**

Comment: I'm sorry friend, you question does not make any sense to me, please update context and elaborate little more.

Comment: What details do you want to know?

Comment: Google Analytics is generally intended to be run from the client. It's the client that sends data to Google, not you. If you do from the server, how can you establish the correct user context? You'll need to find some way to do it from the client.

Answer (score 0):

I used C# to register transaction events in Google Analytics. I found this code for an analytics wrapper class very usefull https://gist.github.com/0liver/11229128

He used a HttpWebRequest to track events in Google Analytics.
It worked for me.

I also created a console application for registering transactions that is available on Bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/gterlouw/analyticsconsoleexample.git

To grab the client id I used the following code to grab it from the cookie:

```
    var gaCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["_ga"];
    var gaSplitValue = gaCookie != null && gaCookie.Value.Split('.').Length == 4 ? gaCookie.Value.Split('.') : null;
    var clientId = gaSplitValue != null ? string.Format("{0}.{1}", gaSplitValue[2], gaSplitValue[3]) : "555";
```

If you want to grab it with javascript you might want to use this

```
ga(function(tracker) {
   var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
```

Javascript maybe a safer option cause if Google decides to change the name of the cookie it will still be able to fetch the cookie while if you have it in your C# code it probably will need a code update or config change.

If you add the clientId as the value for the cid key in the postData from the example code. Google Analytics will link this to your current client.

```
var postData = new Dictionary<string, string>
                       {
                           { "v", "1" },
                           { "tid", "UA-XXXXXX-XX" },
                           { "cid", clientId },
                           { "t", type.ToString() },
                           { "ec", category },
                           { "ea", action },
                       };
```

Comment: I couldn't find a client session ID / UUID and/or client IP to send to google analytics from this code. How does the google analytics server can extract my user location, and to connect the user that sends the events to the events themselves, without this information?

Comment: In this example we are using the cid = 555 that is anonymous. I think the only way to get the current client id in backend is to grab it from the cookie or pass it to the backend with javascript.